# mssql query join to work out esclation person based on discounts percentage

Tags: sql-server, join, case

Hi I have the below working query(mssql)

```
select 
max(load_number) load_number,max(linediscount) maxlinediscount,max(CustomerBand) customer_band

  from [Linked_Order_lines] 
  join [Customer_Order_Summary]
  on [Customer_Order_Summary].[CustomerOrderID]=[Linked_Order_lines].[load_number]
  join [Customers]
  on Customers.CustomerName=Customer_Order_Summary.CustomerName
  join Customer_Order_lines
  on Customer_Order_Summary.CustomerOrderID=Customer_Order_lines.CustomerOrderID
  join price_escalation_bands
  on price_escalation_bands.band=Customer_Order_Summary.CustomerBand

  where [linked_order_id] in 
  (
    select [linkedorderid] from 
    [Linked_Order_Summary] join [Linked_Order_lines] on
    [Linked_Order_Summary].[linkedorderid] = [Linked_Order_lines].[linked_order_id]
    where [load_number]='7'
  ) 
  and Customer_Order_lines.linestatus='current'

    group by load_number
```

This produces the result

[image]

In this query, I have already joined to the table `price_escalation_bands` which looks like this:

[image]

What I am wanting to do, is compare the `maxlinediscount` from my query with the `discount` column of table `price_escalation_bands` and return the user id (fk_salesman_userid) of the record in the table that is the next greatest. so discount of 11 would go to discount 15 and return `fk_salesman_userid` 9. if the discount was 18, it would go to 100 and return `fk_salesman_userid` 21.

I am basically trying to work out the `fk_salesman_userid` that can approve the discount in `maxlinediscount`

So desired output would be:

[image]

Do I need a case statement and if so how do I use it with the max statements in my existing select statement?

thanks in advance as aways

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While joining the price_escalation_bands you can use one more condition for discount.
Check the [**FIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/58464/6). Here I have tried with the result in a temp table. You can try the same subquery with your `join price_escalation_bands` by passing the `max(linediscount)`. 
Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks Pradeeshnarayan, greatly appreciated. In the end I couldn't get this done without a temp table.

Answer (score 0):

Final Working syntax:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#linkloads') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
DROP TABLE #linkloads
END

CREATE TABLE #linkloads
(
maxlinediscount [decimal](10,3),
customer_band [varchar](50),
load_number [int],
totalcost [decimal](10,3),
period [datetime],
CreditLimit[decimal](10,3),
CurrentBalance[decimal](10,3),
CustomerName [varchar](100),
TotalCubes[decimal](10,3),
TreatedCubes[decimal](10,3),
NormalCubes[decimal](10,3),
PricingIssue[bit]
);



insert into #linkloads

select max(linediscount) maxlinediscount,max(CustomerBand) customer_band,max(load_number) load_number,max(totalcost) totalcost,max(Customer_Order_Summary.PeriodStart) period,max(Customers.CreditLimit) CreditLimit ,max(Customers.CurrentBalance)CurrentBalance,max(Customer_Order_Summary.CustomerName)CustomerName,max(TotalCubes) TotalCubes,max(TreatedCubes)TreatedCubes ,max(TotalCubes-TreatedCubes) as NormalCubes,sum(case when pricingissue=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) pricingissue

  from [Linked_Order_lines] 
  join [Customer_Order_Summary]
  on [Customer_Order_Summary].[CustomerOrderID]=[Linked_Order_lines].[load_number]
  join [Customers]
  on Customers.CustomerName=Customer_Order_Summary.CustomerName
  join Customer_Order_lines
  on Customer_Order_Summary.CustomerOrderID=Customer_Order_lines.CustomerOrderID
   where [linked_order_id] in 
  (
    select [linkedorderid] from 
    [Linked_Order_Summary] join [Linked_Order_lines] on
    [Linked_Order_Summary].[linkedorderid] = [Linked_Order_lines].[linked_order_id]
    where [load_number]='10'
  ) 
  and Customer_Order_lines.linestatus='current'
     group by load_number;

select * from #linkloads;

select load_number,maxlinediscount,customer_band,[Salesman_Discounts_per_band].fk_salesman_userid,totalcost,period,creditlimit,currentbalance,customername,totalcubes,treatedcubes,normalcubes,pricingissue from #linkloads
left outer JOIN [Salesman_Discounts_per_band] on [Salesman_Discounts_per_band].band=#linkloads.customer_band
AND [Salesman_Discounts_per_band].[discount_allowed] = (
  SELECT top 1 [Salesman_Discounts_per_band].[discount_allowed]
  FROM [Salesman_Discounts_per_band]
  WHERE [Salesman_Discounts_per_band].band=#linkloads.customer_band
  AND [Salesman_Discounts_per_band].[discount_allowed]<=#linkloads.maxlinediscount
  ORDER BY [Salesman_Discounts_per_band].[discount_allowed]
)
;
```